# Model validator google app engine - BadValueError

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've got `ndb` model from google app engine and a validator. But when I'm using postman to try the validation out and enforce an int from the string that postman generates. I still get a BadValueError: `BadValueError: Expected integer, got u'2'`

What goes awry?

```
def int_validator(prop, val):
    if val:
        val = int(val)
        return val

class TwitterUser(ndb.Model):
    """Model for twitter users"""
    screen_name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    followers_count = ndb.IntegerProperty(validator=int_validator)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ndb.IntegerProperty`'s `_validate()` method [will run before your custom validator](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py#1550) and thus the raised exception.

For your code to work you'd either need to use `ndb.Property` instead or inherit from `ndb.IntegerProperty` and override its `_validate()` method with yours.

The first solution would look something like this:

```
def int_validator(prop, val):
    if val:
        val = int(val)
        return val

class TwitterUser(ndb.Model):
    """Model for twitter users"""
    screen_name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    followers_count = ndb.Property(validator=int_validator)
```

The second one would be something like this:

```
class CustomIntegerProperty(ndb.IntegerProperty):
    def _validate(self, value):
        if val:
            val = int(val)
            return val
        # you still need to return something here or raise an exception

class TwitterUser(ndb.Model):
    """Model for twitter users"""
    screen_name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    followers_count = ndb.CustomIntegerProperty()
```

I think neither are desired solutions though as you're probabbly better of simply making sure you're passing  an `int` to the followers_count property AND cathing that `BadValueError` just in case.

Comment: Thanks, the second solution seems like a pretty good fit if you modify the validation a bit. Thanks for including source to ndb.IntegerProperty. That helped!